# Haskell function that counts input numbers and finds how many are equal

Tags: list, function, haskell, input, integer

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell that takes 4 integers as input and counts how many of that input numbers are equal to the first integer.

For example:

```
howManyEq 3 4 5 6   returns 0
howManyEq 3 4 3 5   returns 2
howManyEq 3 4 3 3   returns 3
howManyEq 3 3 3 3   returns 4
```

This is the function I have created so far, it works for the first instance when there is no input matching the first integer. But it doesn't count the first 3 when there are other matching integers, it always has one less counted.

```
howManyEq :: Int -> Int-> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEq a b c d = count (head (toList a b c d)) (tail (toList a b c d))

count :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count x [] = 0
count x (y:ys)
 | x == y = 1 + (count x ys)
 | otherwise = count x ys

toList :: Int -> Int-> Int -> Int -> [Int]
toList a b c d = [a,b,c,d]
```

My function gives me:

```
howManyEq 3 4 5 6   returns 0
howManyEq 3 4 3 5   returns 1
howManyEq 3 4 3 3   returns 2
howManyEq 3 3 3 3   returns 3
```

I'm not sure how to count the first integer when the other input integers are equal.

Comment: Given your logic, `howManyEq` can never return 1. Create function that returns `+ 1` to what you're returning now. Feed that result into a function that is defined as `f 1 = 0` and `f a = a`...

Comment: Wel is your example not incorrect? Shouldn't the first return `1`. If that's the case, this is a typical off by one error.

Comment: `howManyEq 3 4 3 5` should return 2 because it counts both instances of 3. But `howManyEq 3 4 5 6` should return 0. I know its kinda illogical, but this is the way my teacher wants it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `count` function counts the number of equal elements in the remainder of the "list". If that number is zero, your teacher wants the result to be zero. If there is one or more, it returns the amount counted in the remainder of the list, but since there is already one element in the head of the list, you should do +1. You can do this by implementing a helper function:

```
fix :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a
fix 0 = 0
fix n = n+1
```

Now you can simply pass the result of your `count` function through `fix`:

```
howManyEq :: Int -> Int-> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEq a b c d = fix $ count (head (toList a b c d)) (tail (toList a b c d))

count :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count x [] = 0
count x (y:ys)
 | x == y = 1 + (count x ys)
 | otherwise = count x ys

toList :: Int -> Int-> Int -> Int -> [Int]
toList a b c d = [a,b,c,d]
```

additional advice:

- You use `head (toList a b c d)` in your call to count. But you already know in advance that this is `a`, so omit this.
- The same with the tail: simply only feed the last three arguments, so: `toList b c d`.
- Use the most generic type signature possible: for `toList :: a -> a -> a -> [a]` (given the previous fix), for `count :: (Eq a, Num b) => a -> [a] -> b`, and for `howManyEq :: (Eq a, Eq b, Num b) => a -> a -> a -> a -> b`.
- If you define the same thing multiple time, you can use a `where t = ...` clause, like `where cys = count x ys`

This would result in something like:

```
fix :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a
fix 0 = 0
fix n = n+1

howManyEq :: (Eq a, Eq b, Num b) => a -> a -> a -> a -> b
howManyEq a b c d = fix $ count a $ toList b c d

count :: (Eq a, Num b) => a -> [a] -> b
count x [] = 0
count x (y:ys)
 | x == y = 1 + cys
 | otherwise = cys
 where cys = count x ys

toList :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
toList a b c = [a,b,c]
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed, thank you. And I'll take your advice with making it neater, I didn't realize there were some things I could leave out.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class HowManyEq a where
  howManyEq' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> a

instance HowManyEq Int where
  howManyEq' count x y = count + fromEnum (x == y)
  {-# INLINE howManyEq' #-}

instance (HowManyEq a, b ~ Int) => HowManyEq (b -> a) where
  howManyEq' count x y b = (howManyEq' $! count + fromEnum (b == x)) x y
  {-# INLINE howManyEq' #-}

howManyEq :: HowManyEq a => Int -> Int -> a
howManyEq = howManyEq' 0

howManyEq4 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEq4 x y z w =
  case howManyEq x y z w of
    0 -> 0
    n -> n + 1
```

Comment: This puts me in mind of [FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition).

Comment: @DanielWagner, why the downvote? Or was that not yours?

Comment: I downvoted because there seems to be a serious (and, in my judgment, intentional) mismatch between the intended and actual audiences of this answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the mismatch wasn't intentional. I just have very little experience with the dark art of variadic functions in Haskell, and figured this was a good opportunity to give it a whirl.

Comment: I owe you an apology. The judgment I made about your intentions was uncalled for and unkind. I'm sorry I called it out, and even more sorry I made it in the first place.

Comment: @DanielWagner, apology certainly accepted. Everyone makes mistakes!